# Taking a particular element's value from a dynamically generated HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently writing an (exercise) app that calculates parliament seat shares based on voting results.
Most of it is done, but I have a table which shows all possible (three party) coalitions

The below example is with already generated table.

```
<table id="coalitionTable" style="display: block;">
    <caption>Possible three party coalitions</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Coalition</th>
        <th>Seats</th>
        <th>Percentage of all Seats</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>db + gerb + itn</td>
            <td>175</td>
            <td>73 %</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Visualize" class="VisualizeBtn" name="VisualizeBtn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>gerb + itn + vazrazhdane</td>
            <td>148</td>
            <td>62 %</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Visualize" class="VisualizeBtn" name="VisualizeBtn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bgvazhod + gerb + itn</td>
            <td>157</td>
            <td>65 %</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Visualize" class="VisualizeBtn" name="VisualizeBtn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>db + gerb + vazrazhdane</td>
            <td>152</td>
            <td>63 %</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Visualize" class="VisualizeBtn" name="VisualizeBtn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bgvazhod + db + gerb</td>
            <td>161</td>
            <td>67 %</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Visualize" class="VisualizeBtn" name="VisualizeBtn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bgvazhod + gerb + vazrazhdane</td>
            <td>134</td>
            <td>56 %</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Visualize" class="VisualizeBtn" name="VisualizeBtn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>db + itn + vazrazhdane</td>
            <td>134</td>
            <td>56 %</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Visualize" class="VisualizeBtn" name="VisualizeBtn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bgvazhod + db + itn</td>
            <td>143</td>
            <td>60 %</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Visualize" class="VisualizeBtn" name="VisualizeBtn"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

On the last column of the table I have a "visualize" btn, that will create a piechart with that particular coalition vs whatever is left. Each button has an eventListener already attached checking for a click, but I don't know how to take the data I need from the same row ( coalition name from the first column and their share of all seats from the third column).

I have not really tried anything as I don't know how to begin.

EDIT: figured it out, using parentNode(twice) on the button element gets the tr of that element. Then it is easy to just select which children have the desired data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
btns = document.querySelectorAll("input");
btns.forEach(e=>e.addEventListener("click", function(l){console.log(e.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll("td")[1])}))
```

just change the number in `querySelectorAll("td")[1]` *<= this number* to get deferent items Value.

Did you mean this?